# In 1 Chronicles 27:25, what is the difference between a storehouse and a treasury?

Tags: words, translation, book-of-chronicles

The same word, אוֹצָר seems to be translated both ways.

> [1 Chronicles 27:25](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.27.25?lang=bi)
> And over the **treasuries** of the king was Azmaveth the son of Adiel, and over the **storehouses** in the fields, in the cities, in the villages, and in the towers was Jehonathan the son of Uzziah.

Elsewhere it seems to be translated "store" and even "wine cellar."

Comment: This depends on which translation you are using. JPS uses treasuries both times

Comment: Also, this is just a function of translation. A single word in one language can have a number of different possible translations in a second language, with the appropriate choice being based on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JoelK said it depends on context.

[**Rashi**](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.27.25?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_I_Chronicles.27.25.1&lang2=bi) explains the context which helps gives an understanding for the choice of translation:

> ועל אוצרות המלך. **אוצרות כסף וזהב**, כל זה הולך ומספר לגדולת דוד ואפילו מי שהיה ממונה על האתונות שלו:
>
> And over the treasuries of the king **the treasuries of silver and gold**. All this he proceeds to relate for David’s greatness, and even the one who was appointed over his she-donkeys.

> ועל האוצרות בשדה. **ועל מה שגדל בשדה, תבואות יין ושמן וכל מיני אוכלין ומשקין**
>
> and over the storehouses in the field **and over what grew in the field: grains, wine, and oil, and all kinds of foods and drinks**.

So since the first time is a reference to silver and gold, translating it as treasury makes more sense, whereas the second instance is on the produce of the field and so storehouses is the appropriate translation.

Similarly, **[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.27.25?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_I_Chronicles.27.25.1&lang2=bi)** makes the distinction:

> ועל אצרות המלך. עתה ספר פקידיו וגזבריו על מלאכתו ועל אוצרותיו בבית ובשדה

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is just context. אוצר just means storage. In contexts of fields etc. it would refer to grain. In context to a king's storage, it would mean his treasury. So the translator just used the specific English words for each kind of storage, whereas the original relied on context.